# How to stream the PC desktop to a phone with VLC?

Tags: streaming, vlc-media-player, video-streaming, multimedia, realplayer

I got this famous handy VLC player. I want to stream my PC screen over RTSP to my phone.

Here are the details:

My PC is connected to a DSL router via ethernet LAN cable, which has a built-in WiFi adapter. The modem, ethernet and WiFi have been internally bridged, so data can flow anywhere as desired.

My phone (a Nokia 5800 Symbian S60v5) has built-in WiFi and Real Player, which can stream video from the internet (mainly 3GP, MP4 (MPEG-4 coded), Real video, etc.)

What I want is to capture the screen on the PC via VLC and broadcast it via LAN and WiFi to my phone, using RTSP or HTTP (whichever is better).

I'm unfamiliar with setting up streaming servers, but I need some proper link like

- `rtsp://192.168.1.11/video` or
- `rtsp:////.sdp` or `.ram` or `.mp4`

How do I set up the server?

Comment: It sounds like you would be better served by a remote desktop app such as [RDM+](http://store.ovi.com/content/204879?clickSource=search&pos=1). Although I'm not finding any free apps for Symbian. Is this why you're opting for video streaming?

Answer (score 1):

1. Media -> Stream...
2. Capture device -> mode: desktop -> adjust frame rate -> stream
3. New destination: RTSP -> Add -> change parameters
4. Profile: click the new button -> make up a name -> select the encapsulation (MP4) and video encoding, bitrate and matching frame rate.
5. Click the OKs.
6. Repeat and adjust the encoding options until it works on the phone.